# Can I delete my own edit suggestion?

Tags: discussion, edits, suggested-edits

A few times now I've improved code formatting on a few questions, but while I was improving the formatting the owner of the question changed their code (which I am not aware of at the time of submitting). So my edit suggestions get rejected because of deviation, usually by *Community*, which I completely understand.

Note that as soon as I submit my changes I go to the *peer reviewed* page where I can analyze my changes and see that my edit is *inappropriate* and wish to delete it, but can't find the delete button anywhere (probably because there is none).

So my question is, can I delete my own edit suggestion after I've submitted it or is there another approach to this that I'm not aware of?

Comment: @RobertLongson The point I was trying to make was that my edit suggestions get queued up and other people need to review it which takes additional time from their schedule, and why should they review something I already know is unacceptable. I guess what I'm trying to say is I'd like to delete my edit to save other people some time. *(pssst: unspoken feature request)*

Comment: If there's a conflicting edit, community steps in and cancels everything.

Comment: @RobertLongson Well a few times *Community* didn't step in and other users had to reject my suggestion.

Comment: Ah, missed that one, thank you @Glorfindel

Comment: @Erik unspoken feature requests won't get far ;). It's not necessarily a bad one,as feature requests go. But if you don't clearly post it as one, consider your request to be in a black hole now:p